# Reallocating memory - can't understand the output

Tags: c, realloc

I am trying to create a dynamic array, bu the reallocation fails on the third try.
Below you can see the code and the output of it. As seen, the third attempt puts strange integers in the array and then the reallocation fails. Where am I wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int addNumberInput(int *array, int counter){

    printf("Counter: %d\n", counter);

    int tempInput, *tempArray, i = 0;

    printf("Input a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &tempInput);
    if(tempInput == -1) return tempInput;

    array[ counter ] = tempInput;

    printf("Array till now:\n");    
    for( i ; i <= counter ; i++ ){
        printf("%d, " , array[ i ] );
    }
    printf("\n");

    tempArray = realloc(array, (counter + 2) * sizeof(int));

    if(tempArray != NULL){
        array = tempArray;
    }
    else{
        printf("Error allocating memory!\n");
        free(array);
        return -1;
    }

    return tempInput;

};

int main(){

    // Allocating one int sized array
    int *array = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int i = 0;

    while(addNumberInput(array, i) != -1){
        i++;
    }
    printf("Counter after: %d\n", i);

    return 0;

}
```

That gives the next output:

```
Counter: 0
Input a number: 1
Array till now:
1,
Counter: 1
Input a number: 2
Array till now:
1, 2,
Counter: 2
Input a number: 3
Array till now:
6755912, 6750400, 3,
Error allocating memory!
Counter after: 2
```

Comment: `array = tempArray;` : `array` is local value (on stack). `int addNumberInput(int *array, int counter){` --> `int addNumberInput(int **array, int counter){`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY same output

Comment: you must rewrite the relevant parts to be compatible with the `int** array`.

Comment: [sample](http://ideone.com/YNSenI)